# Django Migrating to a new Database

Tags: python, django, django-south, sorl-thumbnail

I just joined a project using Django, and am attempting to initialize my own development server. When I attempt to do so, the migration fails for one of my apps. A model for this app has a sorl.thumbnail.ImageField, to add a logo. When the migration is attempted, I get the following error message:

```
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE "accounts_account" ADD CONSTRAINT "logo_id_refs_file_ptr_id_7c3d1997" FOREIGN KEY ("logo_id") REFERENCES "filer_image" ("file_ptr_id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
The error was: relation "filer_image" does not exist
```

I'm not sure what the problem could be, as apparently there was no problem in creating the production database or subsequent migrations.

I believe I have correctly installed sorl-thumbnail, and all of its dependencies.

Your help would be much apperciated.

Comment: Have you tried first running `syncdb` and then running your initial migration with `--fake` argument?

Comment: Yes, I had tried that. I fixed the problem by adding 'filer' to INSTALLED_APPS. However, this should have been uncessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pulling the answer provided by Johndt6 from a comment to this answer for future search-ability.

The solution is to add `filer` to the [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-INSTALLED_APPS) tuple.