# Migrate Django app on heroku: relation "filer_image" does not exist

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy my django application on heroku.

That one uses `filer` and I even have defined it in the `INSTALLED_APP` tuple as said [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23913608/797826).

I'm swapping the `filer` name again and again to possibly install this application before mines so I could avoid this error, but I keep getting this error when it is all deployed on heroku.

When I try to migrate the database, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 343, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 25, in handle
    call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 179, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 318, in sync_apps
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 658, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "filer_image" does not exist
```

Any idea where the problem comes from?

My Django version is **1.8.5**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

After the migration is done?

EDIT:
If you made any changes to an schema you also need to run:

```
python manage.py schemamigration appname --auto
```

And then migrate again.

Comment: I get `Unknown command: 'schemamigration'`. For your information, my Django version is **1.8.5**.

Comment: And the syncdb wasn't enough? To do schemamigration you need to install South in your project and add it to your installed apps. Sorry didn't tell you earlier. :)

Comment: I get then `There is no South database module 'south.db.postgresql_psycopg2' for your database. Please either choose a supported database, check for SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER[S] settings, or remove South from INSTALLED_APPS.` ; How could I deploy a database from scratch if it could help me?

Comment: Oh, here you should run "pip uninstall South" and it probably solves your problem. But the original problem remains. Can you give any more information about the changes you made or the models you created?